# SharePoint Hybrid Picker for Hybrid Search

Tags: sharepoint-server, hybrid-search

I have recently developed an Intranet using the SharePoint 2019 environment.  And now I want to start the hybrid process using the SharePoint Hybrid Picker.  However, I am running into a problem when I use the Hybrid Picker to enable Hybrid Search.  I am getting the following error as posted in the image: **Online Services Sign-in Assistant required.**

When I attempt to go to the download page Microsoft provides, it appears that the download page for the Sign-in Assistant is no longer available.  I can't find any more information on where to go to download this feature.  Is there something I am missing here? [image]